# How to change the default initial and next for new partitions in oracle

Tags: oracle

This is kind of a follow up on this question :
[How to change initial extent of an existing partition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132013/how-to-change-initial-extent-of-an-existing-partition)

I have a table that was created with an initial extent of 8M for new partitions and this takes too much space. Using the answer above I am able to resize already created partitions to something that is OK, but newly created partitions still get an initial extent of 8M. Is it possible to change this without re-creating the table ?

Edit : my table looks like this :

```sql
    CREATE TABLE MY_EVENTS (
      EVENT_ID NUMBER            NOT NULL,
      EVENT_DATE     DATE              NOT NULL,
      DESCRIPTION    VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE),
      CONSTRAINT TAUDIT_TRAIL_STA_PK PRIMARY KEY (EVENT_ID) USING INDEX TABLESPACE USR_D1 STORAGE (INITIAL 64 K
                                                                                                         NEXT 1 M
                                                                                                         MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED)
    )
    TABLESPACE USR_D1
    PARTITION BY RANGE (EVENT_DATE)
    INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'DAY'))
    (
    PARTITION P_FIRST VALUES LESS THAN (DATE'2013-06-01'),
    PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (DATE'2013-10-23')
    );
```

Edit 2

This is what I have been trying :

```sql
ALTER TABLE MY_EVENTS
     MODIFY DEFAULT ATTRIBUTES FOR PARTITION P_FIRST INITIAL 65536;
```

but I keep getting this error :

```
ORA-14121: MODIFY DEFAULT ATTRIBUTES may not be combined with other operations
```

Also, I am using Oracle 12.1

Thanks !

Comment: If 5MB/partition is too big for you, I'd question the need for Partioning.  Don't forget about deffered segment creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the "FOR PARTITION" part of my query was the issue.

This worked :

```
ALTER TABLE MY_EVENTS MODIFY DEFAULT ATTRIBUTES 
STORAGE (INITIAL 65536 NEXT 65536);
```